# Trigger to multiple tables on INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

quick question.

In my user database I have 5 separate tables all containing different information. 4 tables are connected by `foreign key` to the `primary key` of the first table.

I am wanting to `trigger` `row` inserts on the other 4 tables when I do an insert on the first (primary). I thought that with `ON UPDATE CASCADE` would do this for me but after trying it I realised it did not...I know clue is in the name `ON UPDATE`!!!!!

I also tried and failed at multiple triggers on the same table but found this was not possible either.

What I am planning on doing is putting a `trigger` on the first to `INSERT` on the second and then putting a `trigger` on the second to `insert` on the third......etc

Would just like to know if this is a wise thing to do or not or if I am missing a better and simpler way of doing this.

Any help/advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the given information, it "feels" as if there might be a flaw in the database design if each of the child tables requires a row for every single row in the parent table.  There is a reason that "ON INSERT CASCADE" does not exist; it is typically not considered meaningful.

The first thought that comes to mind is that the child tables should actually be part of the parent table; it sounds as if there is a one-to-one relationship.  It still may make sense to have separate tables from an organizational standpoint (and size of records), but it is something to think about.

If there is not a one-to-one relationship, then the ability to add meaningful data beyond default values to the child tables would imply there might be a bit more normalization of data required.  If the only values to be added are NULLs, then one could maybe argue that there is no real point in having the record because a LEFT JOIN could produce the same results without that record.

Having said all that, if it is required, I would think that it would be better to have a single trigger on the parent table add all the records to the child tables rather than chain them in several triggers. That way the logic would be contained in a single location.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes the split is due to volume. I have managed to get the single trigger to work, when I initially tried phpmyadmin was only outputting the trigger success for the first table. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Not understanding your structure (the information you need in each of these tables is pertinent to correctly answer), I can only guess that a trigger might not be what you want to do this. If your tables have other fields beyond what is in table 1 and they do not have default values, how will you get the value for those other fields inthe trigger? Personally I would use a stored proc to insert to table1 and get the id value back from the insert and then insert to the other tables with the additonal information needed and put it all in a transaction so that if one insert fails all are rolled back.

Comment: It is a user database so I have separate tables for Address, company info, etc... So the information is different but are linked through the `primary/foreign key` setup. The reason is that when a user registers and I add them to the DB I am only requesting a tiny bit of information to actually register, but I still require them to appear in the other tables as default values. Hence this setup. If there is a better setup for this kind of thing though I am thankful to any advice I can get.